# "Misplaced alignment tab character &" error when citing a particular entry

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I've been getting the error: 'Misplaced alignment tab character & ...' even in sentences where the &-character is not used. It says it in sentences where I am citing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}

In the offshore industry this is different as no central organization is present like
the ICAO \citep{ChristouK2012}.
Some organizations try to fulfil such a central role at national level, trying to
provide information to other organizations in that country, such as the Oil and Gas UK.
They collect accident data, however mostly qualitatively, and provide this to other
companies in order for them to benchmark their accident reports to the numbers of Oil
and Gas UK \citep{OilGas}\footnote{Chapter 8 of the Oil and Gas UK report includes the
aim 'to make the UK the safest place to work in the worldwide oil and gas industry'.
Furthermore, it has been pointed out that the offshore sector in the UK is already much
safer and risk aware than the US. Interesting to see is that there is no intention at
this point to organize in such a way that the offshore industry would benefit globally,
but nationally. Despite the fact that contractors, subcontractors and personnel are
from every region of the globe.}. As no information with regard to the circumstances of
the accidents were provided, no lessons learned could be incorporated in policies of
other companies.\\

\end{document}
```

LaTeX says the following error: `Misplaced alignment tab character & ...e number of Oil and Gas UK\citep{OilGas}`

I have two more of these errors but they are the same as this one.

```
@techreport{OilGas,
author = "{{O}il and {G}as {UK}}",
title = "{H}ealth and {S}afety {R}eport 2012",
institution = "{O}il and {G}as {UK}",
year = "2012"
}
```

This is the bibentry.

Comment: Look for `&` in a bibliographic item and change it into `\&`.

Comment: and remove the `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph!

Comment: @egreg sorry for commenting on such an old question, I have the same error, but I can see the `&` in one of my references. When I change the `&` to `\&`, the error remains. Anything I can do?

Comment: Okay I found it, it was biber being bugged, I followed [this post](https://humtex.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/biber-first-aid-for-data-source-not-found/) and now everything works!

Comment: I feel like this post has been well answered in the comments. Perhaps egreg should make it official.

Comment: @egreg ^^ one off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 35):

I can reproduce the problem *only* if the bib entry has

```
author = "{{O}il & {G}as {UK}}",
```

which should be `Oil \& Gas UK`, if you want the ampersand to be printed. Look for other unescaped `&` in your bib file.

---

By the way, the problem of lowercasing material with BibTeX only affects titles, so the entry should be typed in as

```
@techreport{OilGas,
author = "{Oil \& Gas UK}",
title = "{H}ealth and {S}afety {R}eport 2012",
institution = "Oil and Gas UK",
year = "2012"
}
```

No need for complicated maneuvers other than in the title. On the other hand, I firmly believe that the title should be

```
title = "Health and Safety Report 2012",
```

and that it's a business for the bibliography style to decide whether to keep the original capitalization.

Comment: Shouldn't the bibliography style respect whatever capitalization was used in the actual reference? And it can't know it unless we tell it what it was.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez No; the capitalization depends on the style (except for proper names, of course).

Answer (score 15):

For the TexWorks in Ubuntu:
I followed the recommendation to look for `&` in my `.bib` file and change to `\&`.
Indeed, an `&` had slipped in at my last edit.

Problem (same error message) remained though, until I deleted the `.bcf` file and recompiled.

I removed some other generated files too, but that did not help without removing the `.bcf` so it is likely that just removing the `.bcf` is sufficient.

Then everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 7, I managed to solve the problem by simply removing all the additional files in the folder containing the .tex :

- The .blg
- The .bbl
- The .log
- The .aux
- The .gz
  file.
  Recompile the project, and the problem disappears :-)

Comment: That worked for me on Debian as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add my own version of the solution. I had exactly the same error on the basis of the & causing compilation errors from my `.bib` file from the journal Biological & Organic Chemistry. I managed to remove the error by changing the `.bib` file; but yet my thesis wouldn't compile.

In order to rectify this I followed recommendations to remove a number of auxiliary files; to find which ones were causing the problem I decided to systematically backup and then remove one at a time and recompile at each attempt. If removing one did not work, recompiling would bring it back.

I would then keep the backed up file in a separate folder while I returned to my original LaTeX thesis folder to delete the re-conjured auxiliary file, and in tandem, backed up the next ostensible auxiliary file.

By removing both of `Thesis.aux` and `Thesis.bbl` I was able to rectify the same issue. I think different people have had different success throughout these forum posts removing different auxiliary files.

Comment: Welcome, I hope you are not using that dreadful template that also uses `Thesis.cls`?

Comment: No template was used; I've been building my document from scratch.

Comment: Removing these auxiliary files also solves the problem to me after changing all the & by \& in the bib file.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced this problem with the IEEE class file.
The error persisted even after replacing `&` with `\&`.

However, the problem could be solved by manually deleting the `.bbl` file and rebuilding the project.

Comment: rule of thumb, every time there is an error related to the .bbl file, fix the error and delete the .bbl file first before building.

Answer (score 2):

If replacing `&` by `\&` does not work, try defining `\def\altand{\&}` and then using `\altand` in the place of `&`.